# Programmatically add sound effects to the soundeffect library in a PowerPoint presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to be able to hyperlink a substring in a text object and assign a unique sound to it. When I use the following code, I can use the soundeffect.name property to play the build-in "laser" sound.

```
Set retrange = .Characters(sl, strlen)
 With retrange
     With .ActionSettings(ppMouseOver)
              .Hyperlink.Address = ""
              .Hyperlink.SubAddress = cursld
              .Hyperlink.ScreenTip = arrTwoD(i, 4)
              .SoundEffect.Name = "laser"
     End With
End With
```

I would like to be able to programatically add sounds to the build-in presentation library, so that in addition to the default sounds that are there (e.g. "laser", "applause", "chime"), the sounds I add (e.g. "my_sound1", "my_sound2", "my_sound3", etc.)  could be referenced:

```
Set retrange = .Characters(sl, strlen)
 With retrange
     With .ActionSettings(ppMouseOver)
              .Hyperlink.Address = ""
              .Hyperlink.SubAddress = cursld
              .Hyperlink.ScreenTip = arrTwoD(i, 4)
              .SoundEffect.Name = "my_sound1"
     End With
End With
```

This can be done in the interactive PP interface when setting up a hyperlink, but I would like to be able to do it programmatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add any sounds to the in-built library. However any sounds added using the *ImportFromFile* method will be available for **that** presentation. Any custom sound added will be subsequently available for the presentation and you can then use the *Name* property.

`With txRng1.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
    .Hyperlink.Address = "www.microsoft.com"
    .ImportFromFile("c:\path\my_custom_sound.wav"
End With`

`With TxRng2.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
    .Hyperlink.Address = "www.anothersite.com"
    .SoundEffect.Name = "my_custom_sound.wav"
End With`

Comment: small typo in .ImportFromFile("c:\path\my_custom_sound.wav" as it should be .ImportFromFile "c:\path\my_custom_sound.wav"

Answer (score 0):

I tired the code you suggested in the past, and what happens is that I get a run-time error stating that the "Method 'ImportFromFile' of object 'SoundEffect' failed". That is why I wanted to stay with my code as it is currently structured and where I can first add the desired sound, and then reference it in the manner I suggested.

Once again, my code works very nicely and simply with existing sounds (e.g. "laser"). If I can programmatically add sounds in advance, that solves my problem. I figure since I can add those sounds interactively in PP, I should be able to write code to do that.

The interactive procedure is this: Insert-->Action-->Play Sound-->[this is where the default sounds like "laser" appear]

"Other Sound . . ." appears at the bottom of the list, and this is where I can add my own sounds [e.g. c:\my_sound1] )

Comment: " If I can programmatically add sounds in advance ..."   But as Shyam's pointed out, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Shyam has provided the correct way to reproduce the **Other Sound...** part of the PowerPoint **Play sound** UI you mention as a programmatic method so you need to find out why you were getting an error. I have used the **ImportFromFile** method in commercial add-ins so know it works. The built in MSO sounds are stored for the 16 bit version of 2016 here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MEDIA

You can confirm that it's not possible to add to this library by copying your custom wav file to this folder (or similar folder for your version of PowerPoint) and checking that it doesn't appear in the PowerPoint UI (even after restarting PowerPoint or rebooting Windows). It's also not removed from the UI list if you delete a wav file from that folder. The files also don't appear in the registry so all this points to a hard coding of the media library in Windows.

In my programmatic test, I renamed the **laser.wav** file to **mylaser.wav** and then with a shape selected in PowerPoint, I ran this line of code in the **Immediate** window to successfully add the custom sound effect:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).SoundEffect.ImportFromFile _
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MEDIA\mylaser.wav"
```

After insertion, these SoundEffect properties are set:

```
.Name = mylaser.wav
.Type = ppSoundFile
```

Note that I didn't manage to trigger an error, even when the file didn't exist, but in that case no sound is played during the slide show as expected.